# ListBox inside ScrollViewer

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have no idea why this code works fine:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="674" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Margin="0,94,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
        <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and this doesn't:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="674" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Margin="0,94,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ListBox Width="480" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel_ObservableCollection_Property_With_15_Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="85">
                    <Button Content="custom control" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Height="70" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

A ListBox version is unable to show all items in ScrollViewer. What is the trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should avoid using a ScrollViewer to wrap a ListBox as there is already a ScrollViewer inside the default ListBox style.

Answer (score 3):

Just change template for ListBox

```
<ListBox.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
    <Border>
      <ItemsPresenter />
    </Border>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```